# Is there a way to set init parameters to a Filter with no setters/constructor args when adding via http.addFilterBefore?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

Using Spring Security with Spring Boot, and I have a Filter that I'd like to ensure is ordered in a specific way early in the SecurityFilterChain*. Normally, I would do something like this:

```java
http.addFilterBefore(myFilter(), AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter.class);
```

But the Filter implementation I need to use wasn't written to be used as a bean: it has no setters and expects to be configured via a FilterConfig.

It seems like I'd want to use `FilterRegistrationBean`, but `addFilterBefore` doesn't take a `FilterRegistrationBean`.

I can submit a pull request to add setters (the code is internal to my company, though not something my team owns directly), but I'm wondering if I'm missing an obvious way to deal with this.

Here's a more detailed look at my situation:

Following the [example from the Spring Security docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html5/#servlet-multi-securityfilterchain-figure) I have two SecurityFilterChains and I want the new filter to go at the beginning of only one of them.

```
FilterChainProxy
|-- SecurityFilterChain applies to /services/** when the Authentication header is present with @Order(1)
|   `-- BasicAuthenticationFilter
`-- SecurityFilterChain applies globally with @Order(2)
    |-- [NEW FILTER SHOULD GO HERE]
    `-- PreAuthenticationFilter for SSO
```

Other standard filters (like HeaderWriterFilter, LogoutFilter) are omitted for brevity.

The new filter is only applied when running on a developer workstation. It allows the user to fake the SSO creds for testing before they are processed by the PreAuthenticationFilter.

Comment: what about extending the filter or doing some adapter for that filter where you will be owner of code? Maybe post more details how the filters look like and it will be easier to help you.

Comment: I'll just submit a pull request to the team that owns it. I think if I couldn't do that I'd consider extending, adapting, or forking it as you suggest.